# Secondary constructor not being "selected" by the compiler

Tags: scala

For the following class with a secondary constructor - and with no default parameters on the second one:

```
 case class ExecParams(tag: String, process: String, args: Option[Seq[String]] = None,
  env: Option[Seq[String]] = None, dir: String = ".") {

  def this(tag: String, cmdLine: String, dir: String, env: Option[Seq[String]]) = this(tag, cmdLine.split(" ").apply(0),
    Option(cmdLine.split(" ").tail),  if (env.isEmpty) None else env, dir)
  override def toString: String = process + " " + args.flatMap(arr => Some(arr.mkString(" "," ",""))).getOrElse("")

}
```

The following code that is structured to invoke the secondary parameter apparently is being  applied by the compiler to the primary instead:

```
ExecParams("tag", "cmd", "dir", None)
```

The compiler error is:

```
<console>:14: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String("dir")
 required: Option[Seq[String]]
       ExecParams("tag", "cmd", "dir", None)
                                ^
```

Why is the primary constructor being selected instead of the secondary?

Comment: This: `ExecParams("tag", "cmd", "dir", None)` is not calling the **constructor**, it is calling the `apply` method on the **companion** object _(which will then call the **constructor**)_.  You may try with: `new ExecParams("tag", "cmd", "dir", None)` instead, to call the constructor. Or create a secondary `apply` that calls the secondary **constructor**.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Please make that an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@LuisMiguelMejiaSuarez provided the answer in a comment - and he is invited to create a bona fide answer. In the meantime here it is:

```
 ExecParams("tag", "cmd", "dir", None)
```

is not calling the constructor, it is calling the `apply` method on the companion object (which will then call the constructor). You may try with:

```
 new ExecParams("tag", "cmd", "dir", None)
```

instead, to call the constructor. Or create a secondary apply that calls the secondary constructor.

Another way is to add an `apply()` to the companion object that invokes the secondary constructor directly e.g.

```
object ExecParams {

   def apply(tag: String, cmdLine: String, dir: String, 
      env: Option[Seq[String]]) = 
     new ExecParams(tag, cmdLine, dir, env)
```

Comment: It might also be worth mentioning how to add an `apply` to the companion object, so that the initial syntax does work.

Comment: @ethan ok added.